# Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.StackOverflowException' en mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

Me sale esta exepción cuando ejecuto my aplicación de webforms asp.net con C#. He estado debugando etc y no tengo ningún bucle infinito y cosas de esas...

El error no me sale al ejecutar algun evento o al hacer alguna acción, sino que cuando ya ha cargado un formulario, al cabo de unos segundos me sale el error y no puedo debugar pues el programa ya ha parado de ejecutar código en ese momento.

¿Se os ocurre que puede ser?

Código del form (la linea debajo de "!!!!!!!!!!!" si la descomento peta siempre en este form, siempre!, en cambio si la comento ya menos, pero si que curiosamente me sale alguna vez el error ese en algun otro form y a veces no, así como aleatorio, no entiendo nada...)

```
using TestosManteniment;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


public partial class Net_TestosManteniment_Admin_Llista_Total_Candidats     : System.Web.UI.Page
{
#region PROPIETATS PRIVADES ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
List<clsTMCandidat> llCandidats;

private clsRepositoriTestosManteniment _oRepositori;

string _BORRAT = "";
#endregion

#region PROPIETATS PRIVADES ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private const byte _COL_NOM = 1;
private const byte _COL_PROGRAMATS = 2;
private const byte _COL_REALITZATS = 3;
private const byte _COL_EDITAR = 4;
private const byte _COL_ELIMINAR = 5;
#endregion

#region EVENTS DEL FORMULARI ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// <summary>
/// Conectar amb la base de dades
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this._oRepositori = new clsRepositoriTestosManteniment();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.lblErrors.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Cargar pàgina
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    this.lblBoBorrats.Text = "<h2 class='alert alert-danger'> CANDIDAT NO ELIMINAT, TÉ TESTS CONTESTATS</h2>";
    this._BORRAT = Request.QueryString["borrat"] != null ? Request.QueryString["borrat"] : "";
    if (this._BORRAT == "1")
    {
        this.lblBoBorrats.Visible = true;
    }
    else this.lblBoBorrats.Visible = false;
    try
    {
        llCandidats = _oRepositori.GetLlistaCandidats();

        //Ordena la llista per cognom1, cognom2 i nom
        this.gvResultats.DataSource = llCandidats.OrderBy(p => p.NomComplet);
        this.gvResultats.DataBind();

        this.gvResultats.Caption = string.Format("<span class=\"badge\">{0}</span> Candidats", llCandidats.Count.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblErrors.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// per cada registre de la taula Gridview, executarà aquest event(ens permet modificar dades de la taula o afegir noves columnes)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void gvResultats_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    //  Si la fila no és capcelera, i son dades....
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        try
        {
            //!!!!!!!
            //Agafem la id de la fila que estem
            string id = this.gvResultats.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

            //clsTMCandidat oCand = clsTMDALCandidat.read(_oU2, id);
            //e.Row.Cells[_COL_NOM].Text = "" + oCand.Cognom1 + " " + oCand.Cognom2 + ", " + oCand.Nom;

            e.Row.Cells[_COL_EDITAR].Text = string.Format("<a href='frmNouCandidat.aspx?nif={0}&editar=editar'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></a>", id);
            //Escrivim un link a la a una columna passant paràmetres
//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            e.Row.Cells[_COL_ELIMINAR].Text = string.Format("<a class=\"eliminar\" title=\"eliminar\" href='EliminarCandidatDirecte.aspx?id={0}' onclick=\"if(!confirm('Vols eliminar el candidat totalment?'))return false\"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>", id);

            //!!!!!!!!!!!!
            List<clsTMTest_Candidat_Avaluacio> llTCA = _oRepositori.GetLlistaTestCandidatAvaluacio(Nif: id);

            int contRealitzats = 0;
            int contProgramats = 0;
            if (llTCA == null)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[_COL_PROGRAMATS].Text = "0";
                e.Row.Cells[_COL_REALITZATS].Text = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (clsTMTest_Candidat_Avaluacio oTCA in llTCA)
                {
                    if (oTCA.Data_Resp == clsCRUD.DataZero)
                    {
                        contProgramats++;
                    }
                    else contRealitzats++;
                }
                e.Row.Cells[_COL_PROGRAMATS].Text = string.Format("<a href='InfoTestsRealitzatsCandidat.aspx?nif={0}'>{1}</a>", id, contProgramats.ToString());
                e.Row.Cells[_COL_REALITZATS].Text = string.Format("<a href='InfoTestsRealitzatsCandidat.aspx?nif={0}'>{1}</a>", id, contRealitzats.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.lblErrors.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// botó (button) per redireccionar l'usuari al formulari "nou candidat"
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void AfegirCandidat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("frmNouCandidat.aspx", false);
}

/// <summary>
/// botó (button) per redireccionar l'usuari al formulari "avaluacions"
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void tornar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Avaluacions.aspx", false);
}


/// <summary>
/// Desconecció de la base de dades
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
protected void Page_UnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this._oRepositori.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.lblErrors.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}


#endregion
```

}

Gracias

Comment: Debes de tratar de capturar el error, para tener idea por lo menos en que parte esta ocurriendo. Puedes utilizar el Global.asax e implementar el evento Application_Error. Te dejo este vinculo que explica como capturar errores en ASP.NET http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/aspnet-error-handling.

Comment: cuando falla no puede analizar el StackTrace del Exception? con este podrias analizar en que eventos se genera el problema

Comment: ¿Qué es eso del StackTrace y cómo se hace? Perdona mi ignorancia pues soy relativamente "novato"

Comment: cuando se detenga el codigo o si puedes loguearlo debes validar la propiedad StackTrace del Exception que obtienes. Esta propiedad del error te mostrar el codigo cercano donde encuentra el problema para poder focalizarte

Comment: ¿Cómo valido esa propiedad?

Comment: el problema se presenta cuando depuras desde el VS o es en produccion ? si se detiene el codigo puede usar la opcion de "Details.." para ver las propiedades del exception

Comment: @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez Desde el CLR 2.0 `StackOverflowException` no se puede atrapar en un catch, ni tampoco puede ser manejado por `Application_Error` a menos que el código de usuario haya lanzado la excepción y no sea producto de un desbordamiento de pila real, lo cual no creo que sea el caso.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini cuando se genera un `StackOverflowException`el `StackTrace` siempre es `null`, a lo mucho se puede ver la ventana Call Stack del Visual Studio, pero esta también tiene un límite

Comment: @Xavier, ¿puedes editar tu pregunta y adjunatr el código del `.aspx.cs` del formulario con el que tienes problemas, para poder ver cual podría ser la causa?

Comment: @Xavier para que implementas el CurrentDomain_UnhandledException ? si es para controlar errores de forma global esa no es la forma

Comment: Era solo una prueba, ya no está ahi (se me coló al poner el código)

Comment: Gracias a ustedes solucioné algo similar.! Les comento que llevaba varios días tratando de resolver algo similar. Tenía un metodo en el controlador que hacia una llamada aun SP y listaba los datos, luego pintaba la tabla con la información en la vista. El detalle es que en el foreach dejé una etiqueta abierta y eso hacia ese desbordamiento.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Por los visto era un error en la sintaxis de una etiqueta html... Suena raro pero después de revisar el código fuente de la web resultante me di cuenta de ello, lo corregí y el error no ha aparecido mas. Si alguien igualmente puedo traer un poco de luz al tema no estaria mal...

Answer (score 5):

En general la excepción que da nombre a este portal (StackOverflow), se produce en funciones recursivas (que se llaman a sí mismas) cuando no se maneja correctamente la condición de salida, o cuando un método llama a un segundo y éste termina llamando de nuevo al primero ad infinitum.

Lo que sucede es que en la ejecución del sistema se produce un loop de llamadas infinito, y cuando la pila de funciones a ejecutar supera cierto límite, se lanza la excepción para evitar que se termine agotando la memoria.

En tu caso, probablemente en el método gvResultats_RowDataBound (que se ejecuta cuando se carga una línea a la grilla) estás cambiando algo en el datasource, lo cual dispara el evento de nuevo, y entra en este loop infinito del que te hablaba. Yo no usaría ese evento para cambiar cosas del datasource, sino que obtendría los datos, cambiaría lo que necesite y por último, haría el databind con la grilla.

Comment: Gracias Diego, tenía el mismo problema loop infinito